# Codeigniter mod_rewrite: remove subfolder in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i use CI and got a URL like this:
www.example.com/product/id/5

using this .htaccess file to remove the index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|favicon\.ico|img|js|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can i now extend the .htaccess file to get rid of the '/id/' in the URL?

Thx in advance

Comment: Might it be easier to just adjust your routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use routing:

```
$route["product/(:num)"] = "product/id/$1";
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

But if you insist, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]) http://example.com/product/id/$1
```

Comment: Probably the best and easy way to do it :)